# Joint JS - How apply an event on shapes.devs

Tags: javascript, constraints, jointjs

I'm new with jointjs and I try to constraint a rectangle with ports to a line.

I tried to reproduce [tutorial](http://jointjs.com/tutorial/constraint-move-to-circle), that works with a `basic.Circle`, with a `basic.Rect` but not with `devs.Model`

Could someone explian me why and how to solve this problem?
Many thanks in advance!

Here is my code :

```
var width=400, height=1000;

var ConstraintElementView = joint.dia.ElementView.extend({    
pointermove: function(evt, x, y) {
    joint.dia.ElementView.prototype.pointermove.apply(this, [evt, 100, y]);
}
});

var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({ el: $('#myholder'), width: width, height: height, gridSize: 1, model: graph, elementView: ConstraintElementView});

var m1 = new joint.shapes.devs.Model({
position: { x: 20, y: 20 },
size: { width: 90, height: 90 },
inPorts: [''],
outPorts: [''],
attrs: {
    '.label': { text: 'Model', 'ref-x': .4, 'ref-y': .2 },
    rect: { fill: '#2ECC71' },
    '.inPorts circle': { fill: '#16A085' },
    '.outPorts circle': { fill: '#E74C3C' }
}
});

var m2=m1.clone();
m2.translate(0,300);

var earth = new joint.shapes.basic.Circle({
position: { x: 100, y: 20 },
size: { width: 20, height: 20 },
attrs: { text: { text: 'earth' }, circle: { fill: '#2ECC71' } },
name: 'earth'
});

graph.addCell([m1, m2, earth]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why does it not work?**

- `devs.Model` is not rendered via `ContraintElementView` to the paper.
- `devs.Model` uses `devs.ModelView` for rendering, `basic.Circle` and `basic.Rect` use `ContraintElementView`.
- JointJS `dia.Paper` searches for a view defined in the same namespace as the model first. If found, it uses it. It uses one from the paper `elementView` option otherwise. i.e. `joint.shapes.devs.ModelView` found for `devs.Model` but no view found for `basic.Circle` (no `joint.shapes.basic.RectView` is defined)

**How to make it work?**

- define `elementView` paper option as a function. In that case paper don't search the namespace and uses the result of the function first.
- Note that in order to render ports `devs.ModelView` is still required.

i.e.

```
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
  elementView: function(model) {
    if (model instanceof joint.shapes.devs.Model) {
      // extend the ModelView with the constraining method.
      return joint.shapes.devs.ModelView.extend({
        pointermove: function(evt, x, y) {
          joint.dia.ElementView.prototype.pointermove.apply(this, [evt, 100, y]);
        }
      });
    }
    return ConstraintElementView;
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kumilingus/0bjqg4ow/

**What is the recommended way to do that?**

- JointJS `v0.9.7+`
- not to use custom views that restrict elements movement
- use `restrictTranslate` paper option instead.

i.e.

```
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({  
  restrictTranslate: function(elementView) {
     // returns an area the elementView can move around.
     return { x: 100, y: 0, width: 0, height: 1000 }
  };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kumilingus/atbcujxr/

Comment: perfect answer, thank you for these clear explainations!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Thanks, but I noticed that in their [circle constraint tutorial](https://resources.jointjs.com/tutorial/constraint-move-to-circle) the `ElementView` is extended with a couple of events. Is it possible to define other events through the `restrictTranslate` property?

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you :
http://jointjs.com/demos/devs